# I am getting an import error. How to fix this?

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
C:/Automation/Windows/bin/powerconfig/powerconfig.py
C:/Automation/Windows/modules/Pylog.py
```

I am in the directory of:

```
C:/Automation/Windows/
```

When I try to run powerconfig.py file from a windows directory like

`C:\Automation\Windows> pyhton \bin\powerconfig\powerconfig.py`

I instantly get the error of no module named 'modules.Pylog'

Powerconfig.py contain import statement like

```
from modules.Pylog import Pylog
```

All directory contains `__init__.py` file to consider package

Even I tried to fix error by adding path `C:/Automation/Windows/` to sys.path but still I am getting same error.

I don't know how to fix this error.

Comment: Do you have `C:/Automation/Windows/` in  your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @Jarvis yes i have added it.

Comment: ```C:\\Program Files\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files', 'C:\\Users\\taccuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Automation\\Windows\\bin\\Power_config', 'C:\\Automation\\Windows' ``` This is the output of sys.path

Comment: Try adding an empty `__init__.py` file to the `C:/Automation/Windows/modules` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add the following code in `Powerconfig.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Automation/Windows/")
from modules.Pylog import Pylog
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. But i need permanent solution because i have many files and it is difficult to append the path in all files.